# VBA-Excel and large data sets causes program to crash

Tags: excel, optimization, vba

First time poster and new to programming in general. I have a project in which i have to build a financial model to mine for data in excel. I have succeeded in building said model on VBA. I have ran tests on 3,000 line dataset and it was successful. I will briefly explain what it does.

I track a given stock on a given day on multiple exchanges. I download the data (roughly 935,000 lines) The first step is copy all the data for a given exchange (roughly 290,000) onto a new sheet (this takes roughly 8min), then I create a new column to log the bid ask spread (12secs), the next step is what Im having trouble with, I basically rank each line of data twice, one column for Bid size and one column for Ask size. I created a function which uses excel Percentile function and ranks based on where the given bid and ask size lands. As of right now, I have been running the Macro for the last 35min and has yet to execute. I cant attempt the other macros since each macro depends on the previous one.

So my basic issue is that since my data set is large, my model keeps crashing.The code seems to be fine when working with the test data, and it doesn't throw any errors when I run the program, but with the larger data set it just crashes. Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is this normal with such large amounts of data?

Thanks in advance.
Sham

Here is the sub and function thats giving me the trouble, the sub takes in the required inputs to run the function and then pops into the assigned cell. The code is suppose to repeat the process for three separate sheets. For now, Id like it to work on one sheet, hence used the comments to not include the loop

```
Sub Bucketting()

Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim counter As Long
Dim bidRange As Range
Dim offerRange As Range
Dim bidScroll As Range
Dim offerScroll As Range
Dim Ex As String
Dim i As Integer

'For i = 1 To 1 Step 1 'Sheet Selection Process
 '   If i = 1 Then
  '      Ex = "Z"
   ' ElseIf i = 2 Then
    '    Ex = "P"
   ' Else
    '    Ex = "T"
   ' End If

Sheets("Z").Select 'Sheet selected

With ActiveSheet

    firstRow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row + 1
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

   Set bidRange = .Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
   Set offerRange = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

    For counter = lastRow To firstRow Step -1

        Set bidScroll = .Range("F" & counter)
        Set offerScroll = .Range("G" & counter)

        With .Cells(counter, "J")
        .Value = DECILE_RANK(bidRange, bidScroll)
        End With

        With .Cells(counter, "K")
        .Value = DECILE_RANK(offerRange, offerScroll)
        End With

    Next counter

End With

Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell = "Bid Rank"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Offer Rank"

'Next i

End Sub

 Function DECILE_RANK(DataRange, RefCell)

    'Credit: BJRaid 
    'DECILE_RANK(The Range of data)
    'Declares the function that can be called in the spreadsheet cell  - enter '=DECILE_RANK(A5:A50,A5)

    'Using the percentile worksheet function calculate where the 10th, 20th etc percentile of the reference range are

    DEC1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.1)
    DEC2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.2)
    DEC3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.3)
    DEC4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.4)
    DEC5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.5)
    DEC6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.6)
    DEC7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.7)
    DEC8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.8)
    DEC9 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.9)


    ' Calculate the Decile rank that the reference cell value sits within

    If (RefCell <= DEC1) Then DECILE_RANK = 1
    If (RefCell > DEC1) And (RefCell <= DEC2) Then DECILE_RANK = 2
    If (RefCell > DEC2) And (RefCell <= DEC3) Then DECILE_RANK = 3
    If (RefCell > DEC3) And (RefCell <= DEC4) Then DECILE_RANK = 4
    If (RefCell > DEC4) And (RefCell <= DEC5) Then DECILE_RANK = 5
    If (RefCell > DEC5) And (RefCell <= DEC6) Then DECILE_RANK = 6
    If (RefCell > DEC6) And (RefCell <= DEC7) Then DECILE_RANK = 7
    If (RefCell > DEC7) And (RefCell <= DEC8) Then DECILE_RANK = 8
    If (RefCell > DEC8) And (RefCell <= DEC9) Then DECILE_RANK = 9
    If (RefCell > DEC9) Then DECILE_RANK = 10

End Function
```

Comment: What code are you using to access the cells?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to try and see what specifically might not be working as intended? Maybe an infinite loop or something?

Comment: Nick-When i step through the code it works just fine.

Comment: Lance-Im using vba, should i post the actual code?

Comment: I think your question is much too broad/ambiguous to get much in the way of specific answers. You are definitely using a lot of data for excel, yes, but can you narrow down at all what's problematic? What do you mean 'crash'? Does excel die or do you get a VBA error? Are you saying that the code works perfectly if you step through, but not when you just let it run? Etc, etc...

Comment: Nick-What i mean by crash is that excel ceases to respond, I get the Not Responding error. And the code works perfectly when i step through. I tested the model on 10,000lines and it worked fine, it took 5min roughly but it still worked and I got all what I expected.

Comment: Yes, I mean show some code, you'll get much more specific help.  If you want to notify someone in a comment on Stack Overflow, then say their name like this, @Sham.

Comment: @Lance. I have include the code in the question. Thanks again for taking the time to look it. I really appreciate the help and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your looping through each row individually, the Excel way is to try and work with whole ranges at once whenever possible.  I would load the ranges into arrays, then modify your DECILE_RANK code to work with the items in the array.

Note that variant arrays that read ranges in are 2-D.

Here is the fully functioning code including my custom VBA array slicer.  Note that it was only tested on a small dataset:

```
Sub Bucketting()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim bidArray As Variant
Dim offerArray As Variant

Sheets("Sheet1").Select 'Sheet selected

With ActiveSheet

  lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

  bidArray = .Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
  offerArray = .Range("G2:G" & lastRow)

  Range("J2:J" & lastRow).Value = GetArraySlice2D(DECILE_RANK(bidArray), "column", 1, 1, 0)
  Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Value = GetArraySlice2D(DECILE_RANK(offerArray), "column", 1, 1, 0)

End With

Range("J1").Select
ActiveCell = "Bid Rank"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Offer Rank"

End Sub

Function DECILE_RANK(DataRange As Variant) As Variant

' Credit:     BJRaid
' DECILE_RANK(The Range of data)
' Declares the function that can be called in the spreadsheet cell  - enter '=DECILE_RANK(A5:A50,A5)

Dim DEC(0 To 10) As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'Using the percentile worksheet function calculate where the 10th, 20th etc percentile of the reference range are
DEC(0) = 0
For i = 1 To 9
  DEC(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange, 0.1 * i)
Next i
DEC(10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(DataRange)

' Calculate the Decile rank that the reference cell value sits within
For i = 1 To UBound(DataRange, 1)
  For j = 1 To 10
    If ((DataRange(i, 1) > DEC(j - 1)) And (DataRange(i, 1) <= DEC(j))) Then
      DataRange(i, 1) = j
      Exit For
    End If
  Next j
Next i

DECILE_RANK = DataRange

End Function

Public Function GetArraySlice2D(Sarray As Variant, Stype As String, Sindex As Integer, Sstart As Integer, Sfinish As Integer) As Variant

' this function returns a slice of an array, Stype is either row or column
' Sstart is beginning of slice, Sfinish is end of slice (Sfinish = 0 means entire
' row or column is taken), Sindex is the row or column to be sliced (NOTE:
' 1 is always the first row or first column)
' an Sindex value of 0 means that the array is one dimensional 3/20/09 Lance Roberts

Dim vtemp() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

On Err GoTo ErrHandler

Select Case Sindex
    Case 0
        If Sfinish - Sstart = UBound(Sarray) - LBound(Sarray) Then
            vtemp = Sarray
        Else
            ReDim vtemp(1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1)
            For i = 1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1
                vtemp(i) = Sarray(i + Sstart - 1)
            Next i
        End If
    Case Else
        Select Case Stype
            Case "row"
                If Sfinish = 0 Or (Sstart = LBound(Sarray, 2) And Sfinish = UBound(Sarray, 2)) Then
                    vtemp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sarray, Sindex, 0)
                Else
                    ReDim vtemp(1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1)
                    For i = 1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1
                        vtemp(i) = Sarray(Sindex, i + Sstart - 1)
                    Next i
                End If
            Case "column"
                If Sfinish = 0 Or (Sstart = LBound(Sarray, 1) And Sfinish = UBound(Sarray, 1)) Then
                    vtemp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sarray, 0, Sindex)
                Else
                    ReDim vtemp(1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1)
                    For i = 1 To Sfinish - Sstart + 1
                        vtemp(i) = Sarray(i + Sstart - 1, Sindex)
                    Next i
                End If
        End Select
End Select
GetArraySlice2D = vtemp
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
    Dim M As Integer
    M = MsgBox("Bad Array Input", vbOKOnly, "GetArraySlice2D")

End Function
```

Comment: @Sham, I edited it a few times, make sure you get the parameter right for the array slicing routine.  I'll check on things tomorrow.

Comment: @Lance. Im been at this for awhile, and my inexperience is really showing. I cant seem to get the Decile_Rank function to catch the reference cell, it keeps popping up empty. And when i step through the program and get to your array slicing routine, it states that it is unable to get the Index property of the worksheetfunction class. This is the only party of my whole model thats not working, i managed to check everything else, and they work fine even with this huge data set. I really appreciate all of this, believe me!!!

Comment: @Sham, I checked in and saw your comment.  I need more clarification on the Decile_Rank function not 'catching' the reference cell.  I'm not sure why it's having trouble with the Index property (though you can have it come straight off of the Application object I believe).

Comment: @Lance. Thanks again for your time. Basically the issue is that each row has an offer size, what i need is to bucket (rank) these offer sizes from 1-10, and the best way i found was using the percentile function and then running an ifstatement as you can see. But when i step through the code, and when it comes time to rank the given cell, the RefCell states empty (when you place your mouse on it). As for Index Property, it just wont work for me, I dont get it.

Comment: @Sham, did you change your Decile_Rank function to use the array?

Comment: @Lance. Im not sure, I dim boArray as variant, then I set boArray=bidRange, and then define Decile_Rank(boArray) and its step through fine.

Comment: @sham, you have to do more than declare the parameter as a variant, you have to completely change the code so it uses an array.  you probably won't even be able to use the percentile function (I haven't checked), you'll have to do your own quicksort on the array, making sure you keep track of where the values came from.

Comment: @Lance. Ill give it a shot tomorrow. Its almost 1am here on the east coast. Thanks again for all your assistance and effort. Ill update this thread tomorrow.

Comment: @Sham, OK, I rewrote the DECILE_RANK function and made it much simpler in the process.  I tested it out with a small dataset and it worked great.  The entire code has been edited in.  Good Luck.

Comment: @Lance. Thank you. It works on my test data set. I have to go to the lab to check out if it works on the whole set. I've been trying to redo everything on MatLab. But if this works then it is a moot point. Again Lance, thank you so much for everything. You have been a huge help. :)

Comment: @Sham, no prob, just throw me an upvote and an accept and I'll be happy.

Comment: @Lance. Im trying to give you the upvote but it keeps telling me I need 15 Reputation?

Comment: @Sham, no prob, if you remember in the future you can come back then.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lance. Happy Easter Lance, and to everyone else of course. Ive been doing tests on the code you graciously provided and I ran into a problem. It works like a charm upto 65K rows but after that i get a type mismatch error on this row:
Dec(i)=Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(DataRange,0.1*i)
Are arrays limited to 65K, cause I thought on Excel 2010 they are limited by memory. Thanks again for all your assistance

Comment: @Sham, are you using 32-bit or 64-bit.  If 32-bit you might be hitting the memory ceiling, but it would seem in that case that you wouldn't necessarily hit the limit at 65k rows.

Comment: @Shame, here's a good [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700514.aspx), but it doesn't necessarily answer our question.  [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291) is a list of 2010 specs, but I'm still not sure it is telling us about Variant arrays in VBA.

Comment: @Sham, Try adding the `ByVal` qualifier in the DECIL_RANK function, as per [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=177991).  Let me know if it works and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Lance. Adding ByVal doesnt do anything. Ill try it on the desktops at school tomorrow. Maybe better luck there, not having much luck on my friends desktop. Thanks again Lance.

Answer (score 2):

935,000 lines is a lot for excel.  Like, really a lot.  Barring saying using a real database, If your application is literally putting a =Percentile(...) in each cell, I would recommend Trying to use another tool for that.  Perhaps something within VBA itself.  More generally, use something outside of a cell - then store the result value in the cell.  There is a lot of overhead in maintaining those formulas that are interdependent on 935k rows of data.

Comment: Jody-The percentile is not running on the 935k rows, its running on 290K rows. Is that still a lot of line?

Comment: I'd say so.  Excel 2003 limited you to 65,000 rows.  That's a pretty good number to switch over to something a little more heavy duty.  Using access might allow you to transfer what you're doing now in excel more easily than moving to a full fledged programming language/DB.

Comment: Jody-Im using excel 2010. Im not familiar with access, Ill have to install it, but will access run all the code that excel runs?

Comment: I mentioned 2003 as a point of reference.  You can use VBA with Access, but the code will need to be modified.  Access doesn't have "cells", and "worksheets" it has tables and columns and recordsets (oh my).  This will send you down another long journey of learning, but you're definitely dealing with a man sized amount of data there.

Comment: @Sham: You might be able to write a percentile function that's a lot more efficient. You don't need 290K data points. You could build it just fine with 1000 randomly-selected points or even 100, unless you're really worried about points way in the tails of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will directly address your problem, but have you considered using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`? Don't forget to set it back to true once your data has processed.